# Character Impersonator travels back in time and accidentally takes over life of famous person he idolized

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

While reading another question I was reminded of a TV show or Movie I recall seeing (Strongly suspect it was a TV show, maybe one of the recent Twilight Zone series or Outer Limits type shows.

An Impersonator of a famous singer or movie star (i.e. Elvis impersonator or Charlie Chaplin, Marilyn Monroe etc.) somehow goes back in time to meet his idol.

And while talking with the original, the impersonator upsets the original. [maybe telling him/her to do something different that he/she had done in the future, (maybe so he would not die?)] They end up fighting, with the impersonator accidently killing the original. So the impersonator takes over the original's life.

I seem to recall that the impersonator now years later is giving an interview to a reporter and has been telling him this story ending it with something like "I hope I have been able to live his/her life as he/she would have wanted to live it"

I also think that the original had died early in his career but that the impersonator had avoided that fate and allowed him to last much longer. (Matching the time line WE know)

I am pretty sure the original and impersonator were male characters, but they might have been female.

Comment: Can you give some upper and lower limits on how long ago you watched this?  What country (or at least language) you viewed it in?

Comment: Sorry I forget we are international... USA Probably seen in the 90s or 2000s But it might have been older

Comment: This plot point is not repeated but is echoed in the novel _The Anubis Gates_ by Tim Powers.  I won't spoil it but there is time travel and someone winds up rather more involved in a famous person's life than originally intended.

Comment: There was a story in the sci-fi comic 200AD were a Shakespeare scholar travels back in time to try and meet his idol, only to find he doesn't seem to exist. In desperation at the thought that the world might be deprived of his work, the scholar writes and publishes all of his work himself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are remembering the 1986 Twilight Zone episode [The Once And Future King.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Once_and_Future_King_(The_Twilight_Zone))

The main character Gary Pitkin is an Elvis impersonator who finds himself back in time after an accident and meets Elvis.  They wind up getting into a fight when Gary wants Elvis to play "That's All Right" and Elvis says it is the devil's music.  During the fight Elvis is accidentally killed, forcing Gary to take his place.  The story ends with a conversation with a young woman and a final twist establishing that Gary had always been Elvis.

Comment: Yes that's it. found a copy on YouTube. I remembered most of it. But forgot the twist. ;)